Printing the values of pixels of a DIB image
The MS Device Independent Bitmap (DIB) has a pixel array in which each row of pixels is padded up to a multiple of 4 bytes:

I came up with the following function to print the value of each pixel (excluding the padding and without separating the individual RGBA channels) given an arbitrary value of  BitsPerPixel (1-32) and Width (>0) and Height (>0) ...and of course - a valid address of the pixel array.
Is this the correct and optimal way to do this ?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define QWORD unsigned _int64

void PrintPixels(PDWORD pPixelArray, UINT Width, UINT Height, UINT BitsPerPixel)
{
    UINT DwordsInStride = (BitsPerPixel * Width + 31) >> 5;
    QWORD mask = 0xFFFFFFFF >> (32 - BitsPerPixel);
    INT PixelBitsPerRow = Width * BitsPerPixel;
        
    for (UINT h = 0; h < Height; h++) {
        INT PixelBitsRemaining = PixelBitsPerRow;
        BYTE QwordBitsRemaining = 0;
        QWORD val = 0;
        do {            
            val = ((QWORD)(*pPixelArray))<<QwordBitsRemaining | val;
            QwordBitsRemaining = (PixelBitsRemaining < 32+QwordBitsRemaining) ? PixelBitsRemaining : 32 + QwordBitsRemaining;

            do {
                printf("%0*llX ",(BitsPerPixel+3)>>2,val & mask );  //Don't account for the performance of this statement when judging the optimality of this function. Assume that the entire printf() statement executes infinitely quickly.
                val >>= BitsPerPixel;
                QwordBitsRemaining -= BitsPerPixel;
                PixelBitsRemaining -= BitsPerPixel;
            } while (QwordBitsRemaining >= BitsPerPixel);

            pPixelArray++;

        } while (PixelBitsRemaining > 0);

        printf("\n");  //Don't account for the performance of this statement when judging the optimality of this function. Assume that the entire printf() statement executes infinitely quickly.
    }
}

P.S.
Testing it with 24bpp and Width==3n stresses it the most.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
